# Cannot load resource "". Make sure there is a loader supporting the "rest" type

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I face this Error while creating a REST API using Symfony V4.99 and `fosrestbundle`.

When I Run `php bin/console debug:router` I get this:

> Cannot load resource "App\Controller\ListController". Make sure
> there is a loader supporting the "rest" type.

Here is the code of Routes.yaml:

```
lists:
    type      : rest
    resource  : App\Controller\ListController
    prefix    : api
```

Here is the code of fos_rest.yaml :

```
fos_rest: 
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/,  fallback_format: json, priorities: [ 'json' ] }

    exception:
        enabled: true

    view:
        view_response_listener:  'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

Here is the code of ListController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

class ListController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    public function getListsAction()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume, that in your routes.yaml the type might ultimately be `annotation` (it's completely unclear, since you haven't defined any routes yet) as suggested in https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations

Comment: Please share more details - there is no v4.99 of Symfony

Comment: I edited my post and added the code of fos_rest.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

For newest (>3.0) you must change the route type from rest to annotation. [Information Here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/3.x/UPGRADING-3.0.md)

Answer (score 1):

in symfony 5.* versus FOSRestBundle  there is a problem with routes , try:

1. install this https://github.com/handcraftedinthealps/RestRoutingBundle

   #> composer require handcraftedinthealps/rest-routing-bundle
2. then add to **config/bundles.php** this line :

   HandcraftedInTheAlps\RestRoutingBundle\RestRoutingBundle::class => ['all' => true],

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug/error with the recent version of FosRestBundle (3.0.2)
Use this cmd to install it : composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle:2.5.0